# Return string in valid JSON

Tags: java, json

I want to return valid json string.

Ex:

```json
{
 "status":"Success",
 "total_amt": "41",
 "igst_amt": 14,
 "sgst_amt": 0,
 "cgst_amt": "12",
 "cess_amt": 15
}
```

Expected:

```
{
 "status":"Success",
 "total_amt": "41",
 "igst_amt": "14",
 "sgst_amt": "0",
 "cgst_amt": "12",
 "cess_amt": "15"
}
```

I have wrote below code:

```
public String toString() {
    return "{\"status\":\"" + status + "\",\"total_amt\":\"" + total_amt + "\",\"igst_amt\":\"" + igst_amt
        + "\",\"sgst_amt\":\"" + sgst_amt + "\",\"cgst_amt:\"" + cgst_amt + "\",\"cess_amt\":\"" + cess_amt + "\"}";
}
```

It is not returning valid JSON.

Comment: Don't hand-assemble JSON. Build a structure, then serialize that structure with a proper JSON library.

Comment: Do you need to create the "Ex" example or the "Expected" example? They're different.

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: "Ex" key-value pairs are not in double quotes, I want to convert "Ex" into "Expected" through java.. (Key-value pairs in the double quotes).

Comment: JSON only requires the keys to be in double quotes, which they are in "Ex". If you want the values to be numbers, don't put them in quotes. If you want them to be strings, put them in quotes. But again: Don't do this manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third party lib. This example uses [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

```
class Result {
 private String status;

 @SerializedName("total_amt")
 private int totalAmount;

 @SerializedName("igst_amt")
 private int igstAmount;

 @SerializedName("sgst_amt")
 private int sgstAmount;

 @SerializedName("cgst_amt")
 private int cgstAmount;

 @SerializedName("cess_amt")
 private int cessAmount;

 public Result() {}
} 

Result result = new Result();
// set your fields
String json = new Gson().toJson(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about gson for returning json format. [link to gson github](https://github.com/google/gson)

To simple use it you can:

```
 final Gson gson  = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
 final String string = "you string";
 return gson.toJson(string);
```

Comment: Well you may be right. Sorry :) So to be more clear i will update comment.

Answer (score 0):

I hope igst_amt, sgst_amt and cess_amt are Integers.

So you add .toString() to them

```
public String toString() {
    return "{\"status\":\"" + status + "\",\"total_amt\":\"" + total_amt + "\",\"igst_amt\":\"" + igst_amt.toString()
        + "\",\"sgst_amt\":\"" + sgst_amt.toString() + "\",\"cgst_amt:\"" + cgst_amt + "\",\"cess_amt\":\"" + cess_amt.toString() + "\"}";
}
```